# Separate Nameserver and MX server at different providers

Tags: dns, dynamic-dns

I have a DNS + Mail service with hosting company HostA for a domain `mydomain.com` and would like to use the servers of FreeDNS as nameservers so that they will resolve web requests to my home server's dynamic IP.
At the same time however I don't want to host myself the email but use the mail servers at hosting company HostA, so I can download my `info@mydomain.com` mail.

I thought this was a simple matter of adding a nameserver record which pointed to FreeDNS  and a MX record which pointed to hosting company HostA domain.

However they tell me either I use their nameservers for both web and email or I must use FreeDNS nameservers and I cannot edit the MX record anymore but have to deal with it at FreeDNS website.

Is it true? can you explain me why?

Answer (score 2):

When you point a domain to a nameserver, the name server will use a zone file that contains information such as the A, AAAA, CNAME and MX records. Normally these are editable via some kind of DNS management control panel.

Not all hosts have DNS management when using their nameservers and assume that your going to use commonly used settings for their email, there hosting and everything else. They could however manually edit the zone file on your behalf but if they are unwilling to then you shouldn't use their name servers.

**Most Registrars Have DNS Management**

It's worth pointing out that that most domain registrars have there own name servers where you can use and then setup the records yourself. So there is no need to use the name servers of your hosting account. You then would point the A record to the IP address of your hosting account as well ensuring that the WWW Cname points to the IP as well, generally using @. Then you are free to setup the MX records anyway you want. There is many guides online depending what registrar you have used.

Comment: your answer seems to be completely unrelated to my question.. for instance you talk about A records which are not my case because I'm in the dynamic IP case and then you talk about different things like registrar, hosting company which I didn't even cite in my question.

Comment: Hi @dendini, A lot of dynamic companies operate as registrars and granted I put more focus on the DNS management system and mentioned things like hosting etc, but they are all related to one another which is the zone file.  http://dyn.com/dns/ for example provide domain registration, good dynamic ip support and allow DNS management which will allow you to change the MX records, and... if you wanted to use it for hosting you can too. In terms of can they can they change the records? well yes, but obviously its not something they provide so its time to look else where.